# jQuery date countdown on different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a jQuery count down on my site, I thought it worked fine but after chekcing Chrome, IE it doesn't work. I am using firefox and it works fine. I can't find any issues with the code, can anyone help?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>

  <script src="/js/jquery_002.js"></script>

<div class="countdown" style="margin-top:0px;">
  <strong>Ends:</strong> <span id="clock12"></span>
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#clock12').countdown('31/05/2016')
 .on('update.countdown', function(event) {
   var format = '%H hours & %M minutes!';
   if(event.offset.days > 0) {
     format = '%-d day%!d ' + format;
   }
   if(event.offset.weeks > 0) {
     format = '%-w week%!w ' + format;
   }
  $(this).html(event.strftime(format));
 })
 .on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
   $(this).html('This offer has expired!')
     .parent().addClass('disabled');

 });
```

The output for mobile, chrome and ie is: NaN hours & NaN minutes!
But firefox does show the countdown.

Comment: wrap your code in `document.ready`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass it a date instead of just a string representing a date. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robvdv/hpdmdnpL/

```
$(document).ready( function() {

  $('#clock12').countdown(new Date(2016, 05, 16))
   .on('update.countdown', function(event) {
   console.log(event);
     var format = '%H hours & %M minutes!';
     if(event.offset.days > 0) {
       format = '%-d day%!d ' + format;
     }
     if(event.offset.weeks > 0) {
       format = '%-w week%!w ' + format;
     }
    $(this).html(event.strftime(format));
   })
   .on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
     $(this).html('This offer has expired!')
       .parent().addClass('disabled');

   });

})
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Pleasure. Curiously FireFox parsed your date, although not in the format dd/MM/yyyy like you were expecting, so you would have had problems there too.